# Save clusters in a text file in rapidminer 7

Tags: artificial-intelligence, cluster-computing, rapidminer

I am using RapidMiner 7 to run unsupervised learning algorithms for my research. My requirement demands me to save the clusters (results) in a text file. I found some methods used in RapidMiner 5. But they are no longer available in current version. 
 
Is there anyway I can do it in RapidMiner 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the cluster models using `Write Clustering` or `Write Model`. These create XML output. You can also use `Write as Text` to write a simplified summary of the cluster model.

If you want to save the example set containing the allocation of examples to clusters, you can use `Write CSV`.

Comment: Really helpful. Can you please tell me a way to write summary of anomaly detection algorithms (e.g. LOF, COF) as well?

Comment: Generally, these algorithms return an example set with a new attribute indicating whether an example is an outlier or not. You could use the CSV approach as before.